# Visual Studio 2015 can't reassign keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2015, I'm trying to reassign the Edit.NextMethod and Edit.PreviousMethod shortcuts to anything. I've tried Alt+Up Arrow, Ctrl+Up Arrow, Shift+<, Ctrl+Shift+(+). It appears to save the shortcut after I click the assign button, and if I close and re-open the keyboard shortcuts it shows the shortcut I entered, but when looking at code it doesn't jump between methods. If I assign it to a keyboard shortcut that already exists, the keyboard shortcut still performs the old function, even though in the options it indicates it saved my reassignment. Alt+Down Arrow is an example of this, it still moves the line of code I'm on down even though I reassigned Alt+Down Arrow to Edit.NextMethod. Has anyone else tried this? Any ideas whey it's not working for me? Thanks!

Comment: Did you remember to remove the previous assigned command? VS doesn't remove it automatically so you might have 2 commands attached to the same shortcut now.

Comment: Yes, the Alt+Down Arrow seems to have a never ending list of other functions, so I assigned it to Alt+Shift+. after removing the other assignment. It still does nothing. I'm open to suggestions on what I should try assigning this to as well.

Comment: Following Sergey's post, I'd like to report that Resharper has this as well (_Resharper_GoToPrevMethod_) and it still works in vs15.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a bug in VS 2015: [Edit.NextMethod and Edit.PreviousMethod in Visual Studio 2015 don't work](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1603141/edit-nextmethod-and-edit-previousmethod-in-visual-studio-2015-dont-work).

> In Visual Studio 2015, we rebuilt the Visual Basic and C# IDEs and,
>   unfortunately, these commands were missed. We are planning to bring
>   them back in a future update.

Comment: Thanks so much! It says I don't have permission to view the link you provided though after logging in with my Live account, what's up with that?

Comment: I can't see this page today too. Here is a google cached version: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ih0uUbgyb5oJ:https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1603141/edit-nextmethod-and-edit-previousmethod-in-visual-studio-2015-dont-work+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ru